# css: max-width or max-size

Tags: image, css, image-resizing

On my website I have images that have a width of 720 pixels. I want images to be either 95% of the width of the page (max-width: 95%), or 720px if the page width is too large. So, on larger screens, I don't want to blow them up. Is there a way to achieve this in CSS?

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a `width` and a `max-width`. The element will respect the width, or shrink if max-width is smaller.

This behavior is described on [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width).

> It prevents the used value of the width property from becoming larger
>   than the value specified for max-width.

```css
img {
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 400px; /* Ideal width */
  max-width: 80%; /* Max width */
  }
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
```

Note as indicated in the other answer, you could set `width` to a percentage and `max-width` to pixels. The end result is the same: the calculated width of the image becomes the smallest of the two.

To me, specifying the width in pixels makes more sense semantically. After all, you want to have an image of so many pixels wide (related to the image itself), and want to have a constraint on the percentage for smaller screens. But if you write it the other way around, I won't hold it against you. ;-)

Comment: @BartDude It cares for both. On bigger screens the image is not stretched (because of width), and on smaller screens it is scaled to the desired percentage. This seems to be exactly what xpoes described.

Answer (score 1):

GolezTrol has it nearly right but just has the `max-width` and `width` values the wrong way round.

Below is the correct elements set as you require.

```css
img {
  width: 95%; /* Ideal width */
  max-width: 720px; /* Max width */
  }
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/800x800">
```

- [Max-width MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)
- [Width MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)

Comment: Nice, but I think the behavior is exactly the same.

Comment: @GolezTrol If you set the width to a fixed px, it will stay at that width. Using a percentage with a fixed max-width will mean it will be fully responsive.

Comment: Have you tested mine? I don't see that behavior. Which platform and browser did you test it on?

Comment: @GolezTrol i tested it out on a mobile which had a width < 400px as you have set and it overflowed over the edge.

Comment: I've made a fiddle with the same values (80%, 800px) for both [mine](https://jsfiddle.net/bpbtLkq1/) and [your](https://jsfiddle.net/bpbtLkq1/1/) method. And tested them on my phone (Windows Phone 8, 480px wide, default IE browser) and I don't see a difference. And it makes sense. The doc you linked to says: *"It prevents the used value of the width property from becoming larger than the value specified for max-width."* It doesn't say which one should be a percentage, so the end result is the same. But again, which platform and browser? Maybe its an (un) known issue.